# Lamé parameters and distance on a curved surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

I was wondering if it is possible to compute the distance between two points which lay on a curved analytical surface. The surface is defined with differential geometry formulae (position vector of each surface point). In particular I have the [Lamé parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lame_parameters) of the curve and the radii of curvature.
Since the curves generating the surface are parametrized by angles I can't find a direct approach to evaluate the distance (integral along the surface line) without actually performing that integral.

Is that make sense? Is it possible?